# How can I use pandas to select a specific column specifying a value and compare to a different column not needing specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: List of columns]

I want to know all the information from columns 13 to 21 and compare it to column 1 (and specify the value as '1'). I checked previous similar errors and I did not see any spaces yet I'm still encountering this error, does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```py
hotel_bookings.loc[hotel_bookings.is_canceled==1,hotel_bookings.country]
```

Here is the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-91ca78d709e4> in <module>()
----> 1 hotel_bookings.loc[hotel_bookings.is_canceled==1,hotel_bookings.country]

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Index(['PRT', 'PRT', 'GBR', 'GBR', 'GBR', 'GBR', 'PRT', 'PRT', 'PRT', 'PRT',\n       ...\n       'DEU', 'DEU', 'JPN', 'DEU', 'BEL', 'BEL', 'FRA', 'DEU', 'GBR', 'DEU'],\n      dtype='object', length=119390)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: For future reference, please [stick to pasting code as text instead of as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13095028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead Series `hotel_bookings.country` use only column name `country`:

```
hotel_bookings.loc[hotel_bookings.is_canceled==1, 'country']
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know if I wanted to compare multiple column can I use this method as well?

Comment: @AliceT - sure, then change `hotel_bookings.is_canceled==1` to `(hotel_bookings.is_canceled==1) & (hotel_bookings.babies==1)` if need compare also if babies is 1.